# Flink drop late records even I specified the side output

Tags: apache-flink

I use flink to process dynamoDB stream data.
Watermark strategy: periodic, extract approximate time stamp from stream events and use it under withTimeStampAssigner.
Idleness: 10s(may not be useful at all as we only use parallism of 1.)

The data work flow looks like this:
`InputStream.assignTimeStampsAndWatermarks().keyby().window(TumblingEventTimeWindow.of(1min).sideOutputLateData().reduce().map()`

Then I getSideOutput(), and process the late events using exactly similar above workflow with small change such as no need to assign time stamp and watermark, no need for late output.

My logs show that all things work perfectly if ddb stream data has right timstamp, the corresponding window can close without issue and I can see the output after window is closed.

However, after I introduced late events, the late records processing logic is never triggered. I am sure that the late record’s timestamp corresponding window has closed. I put a log after I call getSideOutPut(), it never triggered. I used debugger and I am sure the getSideOutput() code is not triggered as well.

Can someone help to check this issue? Thank you.

I tried to use a different watermark strategy for late records logic. This doesn’t work as well. I want to understand why the late records are not collected to the late stream.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more details from your implementation is difficult to give an accurate diagnosis, but based on your description, I wouldn't expect this to work:

> Then I getSideOutput(), and process the late events using exactly similar above workflow with small change such as no need to assign time stamp and watermark, no need for late output.

If you are trying to apply event time windowing to the stream of late events, that's not going to work unless you adjust the allowed lateness for those windows enough to accommodate them.

As a starting point, have you tried printing the stream of late events?

Comment: Thank you for the comment,  David. For every record, before it goes to any window, I already assigned timestamp in the workflow, I put a log in the strategy of assignTimesStampAndWatermark, so I can see the extracted timestamp for every record I generated into the input stream. Same for the late records. I expected that the late records will go to late stream automatically. But they don’t. why do you think that the late records may not have timestamp and watermarks. For Watermark, I only need to assign it once, why it can disappear? The workflow clearly first extract time and assign.

Comment: I put log in the strategy which is assigned to assignTimesStampAndWatermark(), it triggered and log the late records and extract timestamp. This happened for all normal records and late records. After I generated the late records, I then generated the normal ones, the normal ones were processed correctly.  But not for late records.

Comment: I think the late records don’t even go to late stream. I put a log to print record in the stream. Apparently, I don’t see the log, not alone triggering the rest logic especially for processing the late records. So I don’t know where the late records go.

Comment: You're right that the late events have timestamps and watermarks; I've adjusted my answer to better explain what I was thinking.

Comment: Everything sounds about right. I think I'd need to see the code to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: FWIW, a window's side output for late events won't capture all late events -- only events that are later than the allowed lateness go to the side output.